# Saving a userProfile using django-registration

Tags: python, django

i'm using Django registration, and unlike everybody else, I seem to have the opposite problem. My User object is saved fine, but my UserProfile object isn't!

I followed this website:

```
http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/
```

which was really good, and so now i have:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    YESNO = [
        (True,mark_safe('<img src="/static_files/greenTick.png"/>')),
        (False,mark_safe('<img src="/static_files/redCross.png"/>'))]

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('isTweeting','points','user')
        fields = ('display_name','first_name','last_name','email','gravatar')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].initial = self.instance.user.email
        self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.user.first_name
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.user.last_name
        self.fields['display_name'].initial = self.instance.user.username
        self.fields['gravatar'].initial = self.instance.usesGravatar

    #add in the input to size it juuuuust right.
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Primary email",help_text='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wideInput'}))
    first_name = forms.Field(label="First name",help_text='',required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wideInput'}))
    last_name = forms.Field(label="Last name",help_text='',required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wideInput'}))
    display_name = forms.Field(label="Display name",help_text='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wideInput'}))
    gravatar = ImgModelChoiceField(label='Gravatar', choices=YESNO, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=ImgRadioFieldRenderer))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Update the primary email address on the related User object as well.
        """
        u = self.instance.user
        u.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        u.username = self.cleaned_data['display_name']
        u.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        u.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        u.save()

        self.instance.gravatar = (self.cleaned_data['gravatar'] == 'True')
        profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        return profile
```

this object is passed into the  Django-profile as the form_class for use, as described in the website above. The problem i have is that when i submit my form, while the "User" data is updated correctly - any changes in the email or whatnot propagate to the db - the change to the "gravatar" value is not sent. Also no error is thrown.

Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Have you got the signal connected up to create the user profile?  something like this in models: def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

Comment: yep, the user profile is created at the time of a new user signing in

Comment: no, never! bounty tiiiiiiiiiiiime

Comment: It would be good if you also share your profile model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess here

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    self.instance.gravatar = (self.cleaned_data['gravatar'] == 'True')
    profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    return profile
```

It seems you are using a custom widget, and by the looks of things you need to change the string `'True'` (passed back from the form) to a boolean `True` before saving it to the DB. When you call `save()` on the next line though, the `ModelForm` will overwrite the value you have given `self.instance.gravatar` with the data directly from the form's `cleaned_data`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L351

---

Also, in `__init__`, you don't need to include

```
self.fields['gravatar'].initial = self.instance.usesGravatar
```

as this field is already bound to the model form and will be automatically populated (if the `UserProfile` is being edited for example) when you instantiate the form along with an instance in your view.

---

Finally, in your `Meta`, you don't need to include both `excludes` and `fields`, one or the other should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider suggestions from @Timmy.
The only thing which else should be noticed is in this line:

```
profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

By default the `save` method has `commit=True`. Verify that the function which is calling this Form might be sending `commit=False` in `args` or `kwargs`. If yes then you have to manually save the profile `profile.save()` before returning because `commit=False` means the changes will not reflect to the db.

And why you are allowing user to update both username and email? How you will keep track of the registration process if you are allowing to update both fields? Usually user sign up using their email. Define your criteria which field(username or email) you want to kept unchanged.

**Update**

Also you are doing one more thing wrong in your save function. You are updating the email, username, firstname and lastname in user taken from `instance.user`. But that instance overwritten when profile form default save is call here `profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)`. What you should do is to update those fields using the `user = profile.user` The `profile` which is returned by the `super`. Your `save` function should be looked like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Update the primary email address on the related User object as well.
    """
    profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    u = profile.user
    u.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    u.username = self.cleaned_data['display_name']
    u.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    u.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    u.save()
    #profile.save() #if commit=False in kwargs
    return profile
```